# R: Using function `max` in `by`

Tags: r

Newbie question here, but I am trying to use by on a dataframe named x2. x2$second is numeric, but somehow I am still receiving this error.

```
x2<-data.frame(first=c("a","a","a","b","b","b"),second=c(1,2,NA,1,3,5))
x2
#  first second
#1     a      1
#2     a      2
#3     a     NA
#4     b      1
#5     b      3
#6     b      5
by(x2,x2$first,max,na.rm=TRUE)
#Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
#  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument should only contain the data you want to apply `max` to, not your whole dataframe. Here, you only want to apply it to the `second` column:

```
by(x2$second, x2$first, max, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
x2$first: a
[1] 2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
x2$first: b
[1] 5
```

Comment: The R documentation misled me regarding the first argument. Thanks for clearing things up!

Comment: @WetFeet, for something like this you might want to consider `tapply` as in: `with(x2, tapply(second, first, max, na.rm = TRUE))`.